# Laptop suspends again shortly after resuming

Tags: 12.04, suspend, power-management

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba Satellite A70. By the way, it supports hibernation from Ubuntu.

When I suspend (either with the menu or the power button), the laptop enters suspend and stays that way.

However, 50% of the time, after it resumes, it will go back into suspend after 30 seconds. Once I resume it the second time, there are no more suspends till I request it again.

Suspension works normally on Windows XP.

What is the problem?

Comment: Old age, perhaps?

Comment: 16.04 sort of does the same thing but you only see the second suspend in syslog it doesn't blank screen or anything. There are two posted questions on this one of them being mine.